# Can't refer to a picture from a different workbook unless it has been referred to before in its own workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple problem: there are two workbooks, `Book1` and `Book2`, and in the first worksheet of each there is an `Image control`, both called `Image1`. However, the `Image1` in `Book1` has an picture, whereas the `Image1` in `Book2` doesn't. So, I write the following code under `Sheet1` of `Book2`:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
     Image1.Picture = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1).Image1.Picture
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error:

> Error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method).

The interesting thing, however, is when I created another image control in `Book1` (`Image2`) and then ran the following code:

```
Private Sub Image2_Click()
     Image2.Picture = Image1.Picture
End Sub
```

Not only did this code work, but when I went back to `Book2` to run the code that failed previously, it worked!

Is it the case that the picture had to be referred to locally first before it could be referred to by an external workbook? If so, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Your first code block worked first time for me: the image was copied from Book2 to Book1

Comment: @TimWilliams May I ask which version of Excel are you using? I am using 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()
     Image1.Picture = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("Image1").Object.Picture
End Sub
```